# NUnit 3 retry test n times

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I want to run the test n times from beginning i.e. quit the driver and run the setup again. But retry attribute does not quit the driver, it just run the test case again.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    #region Setup
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void CreateDriver()
    {
        if (typeof(TWebDriver).Name == "ChromeDriver")
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\ChromeDriver");
        }
        else
        {
            driver = new TWebDriver();
        }
    }
    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureTearDown()
    {
        if (driver != null) driver.Quit();
    }
    [Test,Retry(2)]
    [TestCase("jobsearch")]
    [TestCase("employer")]
    public void GoogleTest(string search)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        query.SendKeys(search + Keys.Enter);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Assert.AreEqual(search + " - Google Search", driver.Title);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Is running tests from command line is an option?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to run the test n times from beginning i.e. quit the driver and run the setup again.

The reason the `CreateDriver` method isn't being called again is because you're using the `[TestFixtureSetUp]` attribute which only runs once for a `[TestFixture]`. If you want to run a setup method before each test, use the `[Setup]` attribute instead.

Same goes for the `[TestFixtureTearDown]` attribute. If that should occur after each test, you should use the `[TearDown]` attribute instead.

Comment: setup works, thank you, retry attributes run test even if test passes first time, my aim is to retry the test only when it fails

Comment: @delwasafewrew Retry happens only if test failed. You may look at the implementation. https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/RetryAttribute.cs#L103. Perhaps there is another reason for your case.

Comment: according to documentation it should only try again when test fails but the above code seems to run even when test passes. I am using Nunit version 3

Comment: @delwasafewrew just to complete the answer and to support Kote 's comment you should use also the Repeat attribute ([link]https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Repeat-Attribute) to repeat n times your test.